# What is the purpose of kernel module dm_mirror a.k.a. dm-mirror?

Tags: kernel-modules

When running an `$ lsmod` command, the output lists:

```
dm_mirror              21715  0
dm_region_hash         15984  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18072  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
```

I have tried to search for "dm-mirror module" and found for example a http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Guide/Modules as result. But there were no details.

What is the **dm_mirror** module, and what is its purpose?

Comment: `modinfo dm_mirror` should give some idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### dm_mirror

is a Linux kernel module. Therefore better search the kernel.org website.

#### kernel.org

"`dm_mirror site:kernel.org`" returns loads of less relevant results. The search query "`dm_mirror -bugzilla site:kernel.org`" does a better job. One of these search engine results links to https://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/frv.html. That document links to https://www.kernel.org/doc/menuconfig/drivers-md-Kconfig.html#DM_MIRROR and there is an explanation of the purpose of the **dm-mirror** kernel module:

#### Mirror target

```
Allow volume managers to mirror logical volumes, also
needed for live data migration tools such as 'pvmove'.
```

Comment: +1 If you have the kernel source, those `kernel.org/doc` paths are in the `[src]/Documentation/` directory.